PointCloud2 is not display correct
enter code hereI have a relatively large point cloud data with max_pts set to a maximum of 150000000. PointCloud2 loads the latest data and cleans up old data every time. How to accumulate and display data each time
This is the code for me to load point cloud according to the official example


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.89.0/build/three.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eventemitter2@6.4/lib/eventemitter2.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/roslib@1/build/roslib.js"></script>-->
  <script src="./libs/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./libs/eventemitter2.js"></script>
  <script src="./libs/roslib.js"></script>
<script src="../build/ros3d.js"></script>

<script>

  function init() {

    var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://192.168.0.123:9090'
    });

    var viewer = new ROS3D.Viewer({
      divID : 'viewer',
      width : 800,
      height : 600,
      antialias : true
    });

    var tfClient = new ROSLIB.TFClient({
      ros : ros,
      angularThres : 0.01,
      transThres : 0.01,
      rate : 10.0,
      fixedFrame : '/camera_init'
    });

    var cloudClient = new ROS3D.PointCloud2({
      ros: ros,
      tfClient: tfClient,
      rootObject: viewer.scene,
      topic: '/cloud_registered',
      max_pts: 1000000,  // 设置可视化的最大点数
      material: { size: 0.05, color: 0xff00ff }
    });

  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <h1>Simple PointCloud2 Example</h1>
  <p>Run the following commands in the terminal then refresh the page.</p>
  <ol>
    <li><tt>roscore</tt></li>
    <li><tt>roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch</tt></li>
    <li><tt>rosrun tf2_web_republisher tf2_web_republisher</tt></li>
    <li><tt>roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true</tt></li>
  </ol>
  <div id="viewer"></div>
</body>
</html>



This is the source code of PointCloud2 that I reviewed. This code updates the latest received data every time, and old data is replaced


ROS3D.PointCloud2.prototype.subscribe = function(){
  this.unsubscribe();

  // subscribe to the topic
  this.rosTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : this.ros,
    name : this.topicName,
    messageType : 'sensor_msgs/PointCloud2',
    throttle_rate : this.throttle_rate,
    queue_length : 1,
    compression: this.compression
  });
  this.rosTopic.subscribe(this.processMessageBound);
};

ROS3D.PointCloud2.prototype.processMessage = function(msg){
  if(!this.points.setup(msg.header.frame_id, msg.point_step, msg.fields)) {
      return;
  }

  var n, pointRatio = this.points.pointRatio;
  var bufSz = this.max_pts * msg.point_step;

  if (msg.data.buffer) {
    this.buffer = msg.data.slice(0, Math.min(msg.data.byteLength, bufSz));
     n = Math.min(msg.height*msg.width / pointRatio, this.points.positions.array.length / 3);
  } else {
    if (!this.buffer || this.buffer.byteLength < bufSz) {
      this.buffer = new Uint8Array(bufSz);
    }
    n = decode64(msg.data, this.buffer, msg.point_step, pointRatio);
    pointRatio = 1;
  }

  var dv = new DataView(this.buffer.buffer);
  var littleEndian = !msg.is_bigendian;
  var x = this.points.fields.x.offset;
  var y = this.points.fields.y.offset;
  var z = this.points.fields.z.offset;
  var base, color;
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    base = i * pointRatio * msg.point_step;
    this.points.positions.array[3*i    ] = dv.getFloat32(base+x, littleEndian);
    this.points.positions.array[3*i + 1] = dv.getFloat32(base+y, littleEndian);
    this.points.positions.array[3*i + 2] = dv.getFloat32(base+z, littleEndian);

    if(this.points.colors){
        color = this.points.colormap(this.points.getColor(dv,base,littleEndian));
        this.points.colors.array[3*i    ] = color.r;
        this.points.colors.array[3*i + 1] = color.g;
        this.points.colors.array[3*i + 2] = color.b;
    }
  }
  this.points.update(n);
};



If I want new data to accumulate and display data without replacing old data, I should need to change the source code of PointCloud2.
My data is pushed repeatedly, and the new data pushed each time does not include the data that has already been pushed. However, I am not sure how to push new data that includes the data that has already been pushed

While I'm not familiar with the js library, it seems like you're looking for a version of pcl::PCLPointCloud2::concatenate

I am not familiar with PCL, but I will learn and use it; The JS library I am currently using is ros3djs, and the specific problematic one is ROS3D.PointCloud2

Please don't post codes as images. [Edit] your question to copy the code into the question as code blocks.
